# input field getting custom attribute of datalist from option

Tags: jquery, search, jquery-mobile, dynamic, drop-down-menu

how to get the attribute of datalist from the option. i am getting the option value

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var options = '<option value="Internet Explorer" key="18"></option>'+
      '<option value="Firefox" key="12"></option>'+
      '<option value="Chrome" key="123"></option>'+
      '<option value="Opera" key="14"></option>'+
      '<option value="Safari" key="15"></option>'
  ;
  
  $("#browsers").html(options);
  
});

$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
  var inputval= $("#key").val();
  alert(inputval)
  var key= $('datalist option[value='+inputval+']').attr('key');
  if (oldval)
  alert(key);

});
```

```html
  <input list="browsers" id="key">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    
  </datalist>
  
  <button id="submit">submit
  </button>
```

```
 Screen Shots
```

> Actual result

when selecting select field list is opening in next blank page and selection option also not working properly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX5Im.png)

> Expected Result

It is sample static option lost it is working fine we want like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX5Im.png)

Comment: Check this one out: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/selectmenu-custom-filter/

Comment: yes i tried that but i is not working perfectly

Comment: i tried above link result is not come perfectly i added screen shot please see

Answer (score 0):

Read about selectmenus in the API-documentation:
http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/

Change:

```
$('#filter-menu').html(selCntryPrvdrSrch).change();
```

to

```
$('#filter-menu').html(selCntryPrvdrSrch).selectmenu( "refresh" );
```

Ref: http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh

---

**Example:**

A working example on selectmenu custom filtering can be found here: https://www.elitesystemer.no/demo/test/36549140/

This is based on the example code in the jQuery Mobile demo pages:

1. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/selectmenu-custom-filter/
2. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/selectmenu-custom-filter/
3. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu-custom-filter/

Comment: thanks Dahl, Yes i changed it's not working, actual when i click on select field it showing first screen shot (i attached in question) if i trying to enter in search field and selecting it is not selecting option then i am trying to select immediately then it showing  2nd screen shot  (i attached in question) and then i am comfortable searching and selecting the option. i don't know why first time showing the list and with out search field enter then i am not able to selecting

Comment: Can you post the resulting HTML-code inside `$('#filter-menu')` after you have performed the `.selectmenu( "refresh" );` operation?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mc0h5n3e/  once see this link i need to do same like in jquery mobile how it is do

Comment: The HTML5 Datalist should be compatible with jQuery mobile. Updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mc0h5n3e/2/

Comment: thanks very much Dahl. it is working fine and when in text field selected the option that particular option key need, how to get that i am getting the value but i am not getting the key.I updated the code above see once it will understand clearly what i want

Comment: i got solution https://jsfiddle.net/9yb6km6a/22/ , i am able to geting value and attribute value also. Thanks a lot Dahl for the helping